# How to cast float to string with no decimal places

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using `openpyxl` to read values from a spreadsheet.  These values are being read as floats, I am not entirely sure why.

```
import openpyxl as opx
wb = opx.load_workbook(SKU_WORKBOOK_PATH, use_iterators=True, data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
for row in ws.iter_rows():
  foo = str(int(row[1].internal_value))
```

This is throwing the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6978279.0'
```

Normally, openpyxl reads in integer values as `int`, but this time it has read it in a float cast as a string.  In the spreadsheet, the value of this cell is `6978279`.

I am converting this to the string I want with `foo = str(int(float(foo)))` which results in `'6978279'` as intended.  I could also do `foo = foo[:-2]`, but this worries me that another cell, which may be read as an `int` or with more decimal places, would screw things up.

This feels like a terrible, messy way of mashing what I have into what I want.  Is there a more pythonic way to do this?  Am I reading the `xlsx` in a way that forces floats?  How can I do this without triple casting?

Comment: It's being used a search term in a web scraper, so it must be a string (at that point in the script, anyway).  But the `.0` causes the search to fail.  I suppose I could just convert it to `float` as I read it in, to `int` when I associate it with it's other search terms, then to `str` as I search it.  I was just wondering it there's a way to do all three at once without this clunky combo of casts.

Comment: When reading Excel files openpyxl tries to convert to int and falls back to float for anything in the XML source that has a decimal point. You can easily convert from a float to an int. You're also using an older version of the API and should avoid `internal_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will never have decimals like `0.0` you can `str.rstrip` it will make `6978279.0` `6978279` removing zeros from the end of any other decimals is not going to change its value `1.12300` will be `1.233`:

```
In [20]: "1.234200".rstrip("0.")
Out[20]: '1.2342'

In [21]: "1.0".rstrip("0.")
Out[21]: '1'
```

If you could have 0.0  etc.. you could catch when the string is empty:

```
 In [22]: s = "0.0".rstrip("0.") or "0"
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.  I've never used `rstrip` with parameters before.

Comment: No worries, like I said in the answer, there is the 0 or 0.0  cases but for all other value stripping and trailing 0's will not change the actual value so it should be fine, if there can be 0, 0.0 etc.. the latter code will set that to "0" as `"0.0".rstrip("0.")` would return an empty string which is considered falsey so s would then reach the or and be set to "0

Comment: This fails if there are trailing zeros on the number, for example "1000.0" would give you "1"! If you do it in two rstrip operations it will work `"1000.0".rstrip("0").rstrip(".")`. I feel like there should be a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

If you need int or float returned (may be for arithmetic operations), you can use a function like this:

```
def strip_num_or_float(value):
    try:
        value= int(value)
    except TypeError:
        value = value.normalize()
    return value
```